# Jhipster - Enable to CORS in order to contact, from angular front-end a paiement API

Tags: angular, spring-boot, jhipster

I'm working on a project where I have to integrate a payment API. Basically, the payment API works like paypal meaning that, you add a button in your app. And one the user click on that button, he will be redirected (a POST request is send to the API) to the payment interface to make the payment. After that, the payment API send you a response to let you know the state of your payment. I have faced the CORS problem. While searching for solutions, I found the page from [jhipster website](https://www.jhipster.tech/tips/006_tips_enable_cross_origin_requests.html). But It didn't help.
[This is the payment API integration page](https://developers.ligdicash.com/integration-avec-redirection/). So what I want to do, is to add a service in angular, that will send the POST request to the payment API directly without going throught my sping-boot backend. This is the service I have created in Angular. But it is not working,

```
proceedPaiementLigdicash(infoPaiement: LigdiCash): Observable<LigdicashEntityResponseType> {
    return this.http
      .post(
        LIGDICASH_API_TEST_URL,
        infoPaiement,
        {
          headers:
            {
              'Apikey': LIGDICASH_API_KEY,
              'Authorization': LIGDICASH_AUTORIZATION,
              'Mode': 'test',
              'Accept' : 'application/json',
              'Content-Type' : 'application/json',
            },
          observe: 'response'
        }
        )
      .pipe(map((res: LigdicashEntityResponseType)=> res))
  }
```

**PS: The solution suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51730409/jhipster-cors-enable) is not working for me**

Comment: Did you find any solution, Im facing the same problem ??

Comment: Not yet, still looking for some solutions

Comment: I have found a workaround that may woks for you, check the official angular [docs](https://angular.io/guide/build#proxying-to-a-backend-server)